# how to add html, body selector style for a particular component?

Tags: css, angular

I want to implement a bootstrap login template in my angular component. The template has a css style having html, body selector styling. When I add the css in global styles, it's working, but when I add the css in the `component.css` file, it's not working. Where shall I add the template css in the angular component?

login.component.css

```
html, body {
    background-image: url('http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/a/5/d/544750.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;    
}
```

When I am adding the above code in the global `styles.css` file, the page is opening, but adding the css in `login.component.css` is not working.

Comment: what are you trying to add in login.component.css

Comment: adding global css (like styling html and body) is perfectly fine to do in styles.css

Answer (score 1):

To style top tags like `<html>` or `<body>` you need to put your styles into main `styles.css` file located usually in `src` folder of your project, there where your `index.html` file is.

Since components styles are encapsulated, they do not affect the rest of application. There were some tricks like `/deep/`, `>>>`, or `::ng-deep` to omit View Encapsulation, but those are already deprecated. Read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).

Comment: ::ng-deep is deprecated DO NOT USE THIS in production

Comment: @user733421 read it once again, and tell me where I wrote to use it?

Comment: @user733421 no worries, but pay attention to details, not to highlights only ;)